# strong-naming embedded resources

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, compilation, embedded-resource

I would like to be able to refer to files specified as "Embedded Resource" in the `Build Action` of the properties of the file in Visual Studio 2010 by a strong name, instead of having to using `string`s to refer to them.

I use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()` which can take either a `string` or a `Type` and a `string` as parameters, but I constantly find that these names change whilst refactoring and I'd like to be able to catch this at build time.

Obviously I can write unit tests so that this is covered during testing, but I'd like to catch it at build. What do other people do?

TIA

Comment: "Strong name" means something else.  You can't pick an identifier for the name, a string is required.  This is all pretty automatic when you manage the resources with the Project + Properties, Resources tab.  The IDE auto-generates the code.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the Resources tab, I was talking about selecting Embedded Resource under `Build Action` in the properties of the actual file in the solution. I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: That was the point.  Don't do that!  Use the Resources tab.

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. I was aware that you could do it that way, but not that it was necessarily the recommended way - often I find we have files such as these incorporated either as linked files or as pre-build event copies into the solution, which perhaps I should have mentioned in the question. If what you suggest is the recommended way to do this, where is it recommended, and why? Other than as a reason to answer my question correctly I mean :)